# Sleep timer on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, autohotkey, power-options

I want to run a particular noise generator on my PC (mynoise.net) at night, and have it running for a set length of time before putting the Windows to sleep (I don't want to shut down Windows, just do exactly the same as if I'd hit Start > Power > Sleep).

I would also like the monitors to be off - though I'd rather not use their physical switches, because doing so starts shifting windows around, reconfiguring the primary monitor etc. **EDIT**: I mean monitors off during the time before sleep, so they don't disturb me in a darkened room, while the noise generator is running.

I've tried simply changing the Power Options, which has settings for "Turn off the display" and "Put the computer to sleep", but

a) I then have to remember to manually change the power options back the next morning. I just want a **one-off** sleep timer.

b) The noise generator site stops Windows sleeping (probably by design). So I need something that will force sleep, as though I'd selected it through the Start menu.

Any suggestions? Maybe some app that I haven't found, or something like a command line instruction that I can put in a batch file, or trigger with AutoHotkey?

Comment: The shutdown command can schedule hibernate/suspend commands with a specified timeout. Dunno about the monitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an AHK script that does what I want:

```
; Monitors off and sleep [Win S]
;
#s::
  MsgBox, 1, Sleep timer, Monitors will go off, and computer will sleep in 45 minutes. Press Win+Esc at any time to cancel script.
  IfMsgBox Cancel
    Return
  Sleep 1000
  ; Turn off monitors
  SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager
  ; Pause for 45 minutes
  Sleep 1000 * 60 * 45
  ; Put Windows to sleep
  DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)
Return

; Cancel script [Win Esc]
#Esc::
  MsgBox Cancelling AHK script.
  Reload
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Start
2. Click All Programs
3. Click Accessories > Notepad
4. Copy and paste the following command in the notepad and save as sleepcommand.bat in your preferred location.

> rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

5. Click Start
6. Click All Programs
7. Click Accessories > System Tools > Task Scheduler
8. Once the Task Scheduler is open, you can create your own custom task by clicking Create Basic Task. This action starts a wizard that walks you through the process, prompting you with what program you want to execute. Point to the location where you saved sleepcommand.bat and set a schedule.

Comment: Thanks. That works for sleep, but a) it doesn't turn off the monitors, and b) I'd like to just click a button and have it sleep in 60 minutes - creating a scheduled task for a particular time is a few too many steps. Currently thinking AHK might be the way to go. If could have a scheduled task that was triggered by an Event, and I knew how to easily create an Event, that might help too.

Comment: Use TimeComX basic version (http://www.bitdreamers.com/en/products/timecomx)